# Preenchimento Vetor Python 3

Tags: python

```
entrada1 = input()
entrada1 = entrada1.split(" ")
entrada1 = [float(numero) for numero in entrada1]
```

Alguém pode explicar o que está acontecendo na linha 3?

Answer (score 1):

Sou novato em Python, mas creio que esteja transformando os valores de numero1 em float e jogando em um array

> [float(numero) for numero in entrada1]

E atribuido o array em cima de entrada1, que antes eram strings.

Os mais experientes me corrijam por favor, mas deve ser alguma forma mais simplificada de implementar:

```
entrada2 = []
for i in range(0, len(entrada1)):
   entrada2.append(float(entrada1[i]));

entrada1 = entrada2
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
entrada = list(map(float, input().split()))
print(f'\033[32mO resultado é: {entrada}')
```

Veja o funcionamento do algoritmo no [repl.it](https://repl.it/join/ubktiwbl-solkarped).

Observe que, quando executamos este programa, a `tela` fica limpa, aguardando o valores que serão digitados. A partir desse momento devemos **todos** o valores desejados, na **mesma** linha, separados por **um espaço** e, em seguida, pressionar `enter`.

Observe que este programa cria uma lista de tamanho `indefinido`, isto é, se você inserir `5` valores, a lista terá `5` elementos. Se você inserir `1000` valores, a lista terá `1000` elementos.

Answer (score 0):

```
entrada1 = [float(numero) for numero in entrada1]
```

`entra1 =` entrada1 irá receber o conteudo a seguir

`[....]` um vetor

`float(numero)` esta 'parseando' numero em um float ou seja transformando o conteudo de numero em um numero de ponto flutuante (um numero decimal)

`for numero in entrada` para cada elemento de entrada irá referencia-lo como numero

se tem ['1','5','3.1']

primeira interação numero = '1'

segunda interação numero = '5'

terceira interação numero = '3.1'

no final seria como

```
entrada1 = [1.0, 5.0, 3.1]
```